# group_by by a vector of characters using tidy evaluation semantics

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, nse

I used to do it, using `group_by_`

```
library(dplyr)
group_by <- c('cyl', 'vs')
mtcars %>% group_by_(.dots = group_by) %>% summarise(gear = mean(gear))
```

but now `group_by_` is deprecated. I don't know how to do it using the [tidy evaluation framework](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `group_by_at` variant of `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by <- c('cyl', 'vs')
mtcars %>% group_by_at(group_by) %>% summarise(gear = mean(gear))
```

Above it's simplified version of generalized:

```
mtcars %>% group_by_at(vars(one_of(group_by))) %>% summarise(gear = mean(gear))
```

inside `vars` you could use any `dplyr` way of select variables:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by_at(vars(
        one_of(group_by) # columns from predefined set
        ,starts_with("a") # add ones started with a
        ,-hp # but omit that one
        ,vs # this should be always include
        ,contains("_gr_") # and ones with string _gr_
    )) %>%
    summarise(gear = mean(gear))
```

Answer (score 10):

#### New answer

With dplyr 1.0, you can now use selection helpers like `all_of()` inside `across()`:

```
df |> 
  group_by(
    across(all_of(my_vars))
  )
```

#### Old answer

Transform the character vector into a list of symbols and splice it in

```
df %>% group_by(!!!syms(group_by))
```