# select and rename stored in variable

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I have several similar data frames with many columns in common. I would like to select and rename a subset of those columns from any table.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
select(my_mpg = mpg, 
       cylinders = cyl,
       gear)
```

Is it possible to do something like

```
my_select_rename <- c("my_mpg"="mpg","cylinders"="cyl","gear")

mtcars %>% 
   select_(.dots = my_select_rename)
```

but using the tidyeval framework instead?

Comment: Would you be open to a base R approach?

Comment: I'd prefer a solution similar to the old standard evaluation solution but with the new dplyr version instead

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984428/group-by-by-a-vector-of-characters-using-tidy-evaluation-semantics/45007408#45007408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lionel's answer to this question [group_by by a vector of characters using tidy evaluation semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984428/group-by-by-a-vector-of-characters-using-tidy-evaluation-semantics/45007408#45007408)  provides the answer

```
mtcars %>% 
    select(!!! rlang::syms(my_select_rename))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
my_select <- c("mpg","cyl","gear")
my_select_rename <- c("my_mpg","cylinders","gear")

mtcars %>% 
   select_at(vars(my_select)) %>%
   setNames(., my_select_rename)

                    my_mpg cylinders gear
Mazda RX4             21.0         6    4
Mazda RX4 Wag         21.0         6    4
Datsun 710            22.8         4    4
Hornet 4 Drive        21.4         6    3
Hornet Sportabout     18.7         8    3
```

Comment: For me, this doesn't rename the variables

Comment: Thanks @Mike H. Sorry, I only thought he wanted to select columns by name...let me edit my post.