# Providing column names as string vector in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I need to provide column names as a character for various tidyverse functions. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984428/group-by-by-a-vector-of-characters-using-tidy-evaluation-semantics) that this is possible with `!!!sums(var_names)` but it does not work out. Here is an example:

```
 df <- data.frame(a= 1:10, b= 1:10, c= 1:10)
 var <- "a"
 df %>% filter(!!!syms(var) < 5)
```

This gives me an error but I await the same output as for

```
 df %>%
   filter(a < 5)
```

Comment: Use `sym` : `df %>% filter(!!sym(var) < 5)`

Comment: Thank you, @RonakShah. There are so many options as can be seen in the linked post and in the link provided in my question. In my opinion there should be a more clear usage about character vectors for column names in tidyverse.